# Java+Spring: Can i upload file if I have path without HttpRequest?

Tags: java, spring, upload

I`m doing so

```
protected ModelAndView onSubmit(HttpServletRequest request,
       HttpServletResponse response, Object command, BindException errors)
       throws Exception {
    MultipartFile multipartFile = null;
    File destFile = new File(
            "/home/stas/eclipse/" + request.getParameter("fileName"));
multipartFile.transferTo(destFile);
```

But i have exception

```
27.03.2012 20:39:45 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke 
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [springapp] in context with 
    path [/springapp] threw exception [Request processing failed; 
    nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
    java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: You've not assigned `multipartFile` to anything. How can you expect it not to throw NPE?

Answer (score 4):

The `NullPointerException` is quite obvious:

```
MultipartFile multipartFile = null;
File destFile = new File("/home/stas/eclipse/"+request.getParameter("fileName"));
multipartFile.transferTo(destFile);   <-----Exception
```

`multipartFile` variable is never initialized and throws NPE when being first accessed.

You can get all uploaded files from request using:

```
public ModelAndView onSubmit(HttpServletRequest request, /*...*/) {
  MultipartHttpServletRequest multipartRequest = (MultipartHttpServletRequest)request;
  Map<String, MultipartFile> files = multipartRequest.getFileMap();
```

Comment: how should  initialize multipartFile if I have only path?

Comment: I have list file names, user select 1 file(radio button) and i must upload this file.I receive in my controller only name file(String) and path(String).I dont use <input type="file" name="file" id="file" /> for select file,is this possible?